# how to run terminal code of speech recognition on qt4

Tags: c++, qt

I have done speech recognition with the help of raspberry pi. At initial, I have run my code on terminal and my hardware is raspberry pi but now I want to run that code on qt creator with the same hardware then what should be the code?
The link of my code that is successfully run on terminal and raspberry pi.

```
echo "Recording your Speech (Ctrl+C to Transcribe)"
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -q -f cd -t wav -d 0 -r 16000 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -s -o daveconroy.flac;

echo "Converting Speech to Text..."
wget -q -U "Mozilla/5.0" --post-file daveconroy.flac --header "Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000" -O - "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?lang=en-us&client=chromium" | cut -d\" -f12  > stt.txt

echo "You Said:"
value=`cat stt.txt`
echo "$value"
```

Please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ideally its quite trivial,

1. Create a new qt project
2. Add your sources/resources into new project
3. Setup the build rules
4. Build your app and wuala, enjoy !

The integration of existing `c++` project into `qtcreator` should not be a big deal, as the `Qt` is a `c++` based framework.

I would suggest to have a look at the manuals/helps of the `qtcreator` [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/)